I'm hoping for advice on how to transition 10+ week old feral kittens to the indoors
While gardening I found a queen and her three kittens, that were 8 weeks old, living under my house. Mama Cat is obviously a stray as, once we got past the hissing defense of her kittens, she loves attention and physical affection. The kittens were feral but we've opened our house and made it possible to enter during the day. They come in for food and have done a little adventuring before heading back outside.
I want to find homes for the kittens. In the past month, they've gone from being scared of people, to allowing us to pick them up (for 15-60 seconds, depending on the kitten) and showing signs of enjoying being petted.
The problem is I have a very small home and already have a rescued feral mother cat with her two, now adult, kittens. I brought them home from my work parking lot a year and a half ago.
My plan, unless anyone can give me a better option, is too close the door when they are eating breakfast. They have a space sectioned off in the kitchen that my cats can't go but can see. I've got a spare bedroom that barely fits a double bed to move them into.
After a few days, I'll be taking mother cat to be spayed. I've managed to find homes for the kittens and I'm hoping I'll be able to have the prospective fur parents over to interact as soon as possible. I know this will be horrible and stressful for everyone involved but I know finding these kittens a home will give them a future. We'll be keeping the mother and expect that integrating her into the household will be a long term project by itself.
Does anyone have any advice on the situation? When I brought home my current cats, the kittens were younger and I'd spent hours upon hours in a parking lot gaining the mother's trust (over a year). Putting older "feral" kittens into a small room is a new challenge for us.
Side note: the kittens will be spayed before giving them to their new parents (my coworkers).

There have to be many websites from rescue agencies and shelters and SPCAs and such which cover socializing ferals to live with humans...
